# Handling of switch to daylight saving time with POSIXct in R

Tags: r, na, posixct

I have hourly data associated with time stamps of the following format.

```
xx <- c("2019-03-30 12:00", "2019-03-30 13:00", "2019-03-30 14:00", "2019-03-30 15:00", "2019-03-30 16:00", "2019-03-30 17:00", "2019-03-30 18:00", "2019-03-30 19:00", "2019-03-30 20:00", "2019-03-30 21:00", "2019-03-30 22:00", "2019-03-30 23:00", "2019-03-31 00:00", "2019-03-31 01:00", "2019-03-31 02:00","2019-03-31 03:00", "2019-03-31 04:00", "2019-03-31 05:00", "2019-03-31 06:00", "2019-03-31 07:00", "2019-03-31 08:00", "2019-03-31 09:00", "2019-03-31 10:00", "2019-03-31 11:00", "2019-03-31 12:00")
```

If I convert this to POSIXct, I get a format stripped of the hours:

```
> as.POSIXct(xx)
 [1] "2019-03-30 CET" "2019-03-30 CET" "2019-03-30 CET"
 [4] "2019-03-30 CET" "2019-03-30 CET" "2019-03-30 CET"
 [7] "2019-03-30 CET" "2019-03-30 CET" "2019-03-30 CET"
[10] "2019-03-30 CET" "2019-03-30 CET" "2019-03-30 CET"
[13] "2019-03-31 CET" "2019-03-31 CET" "2019-03-31 CET"
[16] "2019-03-31 CET" "2019-03-31 CET" "2019-03-31 CET"
[19] "2019-03-31 CET" "2019-03-31 CET" "2019-03-31 CET"
[22] "2019-03-31 CET" "2019-03-31 CET" "2019-03-31 CET"
[25] "2019-03-31 CET"
```

But I need to retain the hourly timestamp. However if I execute as.POSIXct() with the correct formatting option, I get the following problem:

```
> as.POSIXct(xx, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
 [1] "2019-03-30 12:00:00 CET"  "2019-03-30 13:00:00 CET" 
 [3] "2019-03-30 14:00:00 CET"  "2019-03-30 15:00:00 CET" 
 [5] "2019-03-30 16:00:00 CET"  "2019-03-30 17:00:00 CET" 
 [7] "2019-03-30 18:00:00 CET"  "2019-03-30 19:00:00 CET" 
 [9] "2019-03-30 20:00:00 CET"  "2019-03-30 21:00:00 CET" 
[11] "2019-03-30 22:00:00 CET"  "2019-03-30 23:00:00 CET" 
[13] "2019-03-31 00:00:00 CET"  "2019-03-31 01:00:00 CET" 
[15] NA                         "2019-03-31 03:00:00 CEST"
[17] "2019-03-31 04:00:00 CEST" "2019-03-31 05:00:00 CEST"
[19] "2019-03-31 06:00:00 CEST" "2019-03-31 07:00:00 CEST"
[21] "2019-03-31 08:00:00 CEST" "2019-03-31 09:00:00 CEST"
[23] "2019-03-31 10:00:00 CEST" "2019-03-31 11:00:00 CEST"
[25] "2019-03-31 12:00:00 CEST"
```

Apparently POSIXct cannot handle switches in daylight saving time? What's going on here?

I know I can solve this by using lubridates' ymd_hm(), but I pose this question in order to get understanding of the workings here. Is it possible to solve this in base R, or does s.POSIXct have a basic disfunctionality here?

Thanks.

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

Thanks to zoowalk and Roland in the comments for this solution:

My timeseries was recorded without time switches. However my OS time zone does record time switches throughout the year. Accordingly, I need to hand a time zone to the function that equally does not have time switches, like UTC:

`as.POSIXct(xx, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="UTC")`

Comment: Isn't this just because `"2019-03-31 02:00"` isn't a real time? If the clocks go forward one hour for summer time, then they tick from `"2019-03-31 01:59:59"` to `"2019-03-31 03:00:00"`, so R is right in making `"2019-03-31 02:00:00"` eqaul to `NA` because "02:00:00" never existed. Isn't this a bit like getting annoyed at R when it makes the 30th February `NA` ?

Comment: AFAIKT it very much depends on in which timezone you want to work. If you use UTC the problem doesn't arise here. as.POSIXct(xx, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="UTC")

Comment: +1 to @zoowalk If you have time stamps without switch to DST, use a timezone without switch to DST. R handles DST switches just fine and that's the issue here, because your data doesn't switch and you are using the default time zone (the OS time zone) which switches between CET/CEST in your locale.

Comment: @Ben can you please provide the solution as an answer below and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to zoowalk and Roland in the comments for this solution:

My timeseries was recorded without time switches. However my OS time zone does record time switches throughout the year. Accordingly, I need to hand a time zone to the function that equally does not have time switches, like UTC:

as.POSIXct(xx, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="UTC")